# How to Prevent 'SQL Server Report Server Running'

Tags: sql-server

When I look at my log files via SQL Server Management Studio, I see entries saying

```
'Starting Up Database ReportServer' and 
'Starting Up Database ReportServerTempDB'
```

I don't use ReportServer, how do I stop these events from happening. In the beginning, it was just the temp and then when I disabled the ReportServer service, the ReportServer started to appear.

I don't want to uninstall, I'd just like the databases from being started.

Answer (score 0):

Every database that is attached to the server always starts when the server starts.
You can drop these databases if you don't use SSRS service.